# Scaffolding with ViewModel and Database Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, scaffolding

I am challenging with some difficulties in MVC3. Actually, I have a Solution entails three projects inside, namely, Model; dedicated for EF Code First and its POCOs, MVC-WebProject, and Repository-UnitOfWork.

In the Second project, I have created a folder named ViewModels which is a container for the ViewModel classes which in turn have been created according to each POCO class. They also include some additional properties to serve DropDownList and as such.

But I was wondering why I cannot do Scaffolding of MVC as using ViewModels. Let me explain the issue in an orderly manner (this is VS 2010, MVC3 + Razor):

> 1. I right-click the Controller folder > Add > Controller
> 2. Choose an apt name for the Controller
> 3. Inside Scaffolding Box, the first item is a DropDownList relates to Template > 
>      Controller with Read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework
> 4. From Model Class > ViewModel_User
> 5. From Datacontext class > DatabaseContext (MyProject_Repository). This class is placed 
>      inside the Repository Class Library Project.

Here is a familiar picture of that:

[image]

But as I press the 'OK' button an error comes up which says:

> There was an error generating 'MyProject_Repository.DatabaseContext'. Try rebuilding your 
>   project.

In deed, the Databasecontext class involves `DbSet<User>` and other necessities in order to generate the database as I am using EF Code First.

If back to the problem and the Error.. What is the best work around? I've been reading and searching so much about the ViewModel in MVC even trying some in Package Manager Console.. But failed!

I appreciate if anyone may help me on this.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your project. It will fix the problem . after that you can scaffold